# osm2pgsql - Failed to allocate space for node cache file

Tags: postgresql

it's my first time trying to set up a OSM server. I have been following this tutorial:

https://github.com/AnderPijoan/vectorosm (with node why i need to change how the maps are rendered for some specific requirements of my project).

i made everything, except that i installed the osm2pgsql from source why the repository version is too old.

but i get stuck at the importing of the DB, i'm using:

```
  osm2pgsql -m -s -c  -j -v --cache-strategy dense --flat-nodes tempFileErase -d osm -U osmuser --unlogged  --hstore-add-index --exclude-invalid-polygon -r pbf planet-latest.osm.pbf
```

but i get:

```
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.83.0 (64bit id space)

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=0*102401, allocation method=8192
Mid: loading persistent node cache from tempFileErase
Failed to allocate space for node cache file: Success
Error occurred, cleaning up
```

any idea of how i can fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same command with `-S` or `--style`.  You should pass the location of default.style file with this.  You can download the file from this link.
https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `--cache-strategy dense` from your command. That worked for me.